# Python Win32 Extensions not Available?

Tags: python, trac

I am trying to get a post-commit.bat script running on a Windows Vista Ultimate machine for Trac.

I have installed Trac and its working fine - but when I run this script I get the error:

**"The Python Win32 extensions for NT (service, event, logging) appear not to be Available."**

Anyone know why this would occur ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

have u installed the [Python Win32 module](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/)?

Comment: @Andy, glad u liked it, Enjoy Your Python Journey.